# xargs to copy one file into several

Tags: unix, aix, xargs

I have a directory that has one file with information (call it masterfile.inc) and several files that are empty (call them file1.inc-file20.inc)

I'm trying to formulate an xargs command that copies the contents of masterfile.inc into all of the empty files.

So far I have

> ls -ltr | awk '{print $9}' | grep -v masterfile | xargs -I {} cat masterfile.inc > {}

Unfortunately, all this does is creates a file called {} and prints masterfile.inc into it N times.

Is there something I'm missing with the syntax here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also note:  Files are unique names, can't use any pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to copy file 20 times:

```
$ tee <masterfile.inc >/dev/null file{1..20}.inc
```

**Note:** `file{1..20}.inc` will expand to `file1, file2, ... , file20`

---

If you disternation filenames are random:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ tee <masterfile.inc >/dev/null $(ls !(masterfile.inc))
```

**Note:**  `$(ls !(masterfile.inc))` will expand to all file in current directory except `masterfile.inc` (please don't use spaces in filename)

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific.  The files are not actually named in such a way where a pattern could work.  They are unique names.

Comment: It doesn't appear to like the !

"bash: !: event not found"

Answer (score 0):

While the `tee` trick is really brilliant you might be interested in a solution that is easier to adapt for other situations. Here using GNU Parallel:

```
ls -ltr | awk '{print $9}' | grep -v masterfile | parallel "cat masterfile.inc > {}"
```

It takes literally 10 seconds to install GNU Parallel:

```
wget pi.dk/3 -qO - | sh -x
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1